# Event Ordering ExpressJS/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use events to set the cache-control header in a simple ExpressJS web server. The code looks something like this:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
  helper.setCacheHeader.call(res, SIX_MONTHS);
  // If something goes wrong (and we know about it) remove the cache value
  res.on('nocache', function () {
    helper.setCacheHeader.call(res, 0);
  });

  next();
});
```

That is the first route of the router so every non-static file will go through that. I have some places in the code where something could go wrong and I just send an empty 200 and emit the "nocache" event on `res`.

```
if (err) {
  res.emit('nocache');
  return res.send(200, foo_bar)
}
```

This *appears* to work when I trigger an error event, my cache-header is set to 0 as expected. However, the longer I stare at it, the less sure I am about it.

Are all the event handlers resolved *before* then end of the response (`res.send`)? Or is this really a race condition and I just keep getting lucky so it looks like it's working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution will work since events are emitted and received in a synchronous manner. By firing the event with `res.emit('nocache')` the `EventEmitter` calls any registered listeners in the current thread (since node.js is single threaded).

`EventEmitter` does not use `process.nextTick()` to call the handlers so all handlers registered for the nocache event are always called before `res.send()`. You can check the implementation of `EventEmitter` in the [node.js source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/events.js).